# Terraform GCP HTTPS load balancer google_compute_url_map with variable length of host_rule blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm a Terraform novice creating GCP external HTTP/HTTPS load balancers that route different hostnames to different backends.  In a working proof of concept, I have two hostnames supported, like this:

```
locals {
  hostnames = [ "www.site1.com", "www.site2.org" ]
}

resource "google_compute_url_map" "MY_URL_MAP_HTTPS" {
  name               = "mylb-https"
  description        = "External HTTPS load balancer for multiple hostnames"
  host_rule {
    hosts            = [ local.hostnames[0] ]
    path_matcher     = "site1-path-matcher"
  }
  host_rule {
    hosts            = [ local.hostnames[1] ]
    path_matcher     = "site2-path-matcher"
  }
  path_matcher {
    name             = "site1-path-matcher"
    default_service  = "projects/myproject/global/backendServices/site1-backend-service"
  }
  path_matcher {
    name             = "site2-path-matcher"
    default_service  = "projects/myproject/global/backendServices/site2-backend-service"
  }
}
```

I know I can do a for loop when Terraform expects a list, such as associating multiple SSL certificates with a target proxy:

```
resource "google_compute_ssl_certificate" "MY_SSL_CERT" {
  count          = length(local.hostnames)
  name           = replace(local.hostnames[count.index], ".", "-")
}
resource "google_compute_target_https_proxy" "MY_TARGET_PROXY_HTTPS" {
  ssl_certificates      = [ 
    for cert in google_compute_ssl_certificate.MY_SSL_CERT
      cert.id
  ]
}
```

But how can a do a for loop on the **host_rule** and **path_matcher** blocks?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found a [bug report](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/3498) which helped me see [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) are the solution:

```
variable "hostnames" {
  type                 = list(string)
  default              = null
}

resource "google_compute_url_map" "URL_MAP_HTTPS" {
  name                  = "urlmap-https"
  default_service       = google_compute_backend_bucket.default.id
  dynamic "host_rule" {
    for_each = var.hostnames
    content {
      hosts               = [ host_rule.value]
      path_matcher        = "path-matcher-${host_rule.key}"
    }
  }
  dynamic "path_matcher" {
    for_each = var.hostnames
    content {
      name                = "path-matcher-${path_matcher.key}"
      default_service     = google_compute_backend_service.default[path_matcher.key].id
    }
  }
}
```

This is also the solution to having a variable number of backend blocks to use with [google_compute_backend_service](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_backend_service) and [google_compute_region_backend_service](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_region_backend_service).